# HTML/CSS - Animations problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-animations, responsive

I am trying to make different website animations and using responsive design.

The problem is when I try to apply this changes to my header and affects also to my `.heading` element. I realized that something is happening with the height in the `#main` where apparently its height is `0`.

Its probably bacuse the structure is not well made.

Could you help me with that? Hope my explanation is clear.

I share with you my code:

```css
@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(1rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* Esto es para las animaciones */

header {
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.options {
  background-color: #777;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 3.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.select-active {
  background: green;
}

.options ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.options ul li {
  float: left;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.options ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.55rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.special {
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.submenu {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
}

.body {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.heading {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), url(/images/logo.png);
  margin-left: 5rem;
  width: 95%;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 5.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 4.2rem;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

.submenu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: solid 2px white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.options ul li:hover {
  background: black;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}

.picture {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -6.5rem;
  left: -11rem;
}

.logo {
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.footer .bg-video__content {
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 15rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
  header,
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

<div id=container>
  <header id="header">
    <nav class="options">
      <ul>
        <li class="select-active"><a href="">CSS</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="">
                                SASS
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
        <li span style="word-spacing: 0px"><a href="">Front End vs Back End</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="picture">
      <img class="logo" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/C/css3-logo-8724075274-seeklogo.com.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </header>

  <main id="main">
    <aside class="submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Introducción</li>
        <li>Styling block</li>
        <li>Selectores</li>
        <li>Propiedades</li>
        <li>Cascada y herencia</li>
        <li>The Box Model</li>
        <li>Responsive</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <section class="body">
      <header class="heading">CSS
      </header>
      <article class="text">
        <h2>Styling Blocks</h2><br><br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,
          como las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web, y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
          (como Firefox OS).</p><br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,
          como las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web, y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
          (como Firefox OS).</p><br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,
          como las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web, y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
          (como Firefox OS).</p> <br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,
          como las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web,y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
          (como Firefox OS).</p><br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,como
          las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web, y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles (como
          Firefox OS).</p><br>

        <p>CSS (siglas en inglés de Cascading Style Sheets), en español "Hojas de estilo en cascada", es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.​ Es muy usado para
          establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. También permite aplicar estilos no visuales,como
          las hojas de estilo auditivas. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web, y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles (como
          Firefox OS).</p><br>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">

    <div class="bg-video">
      <video class="bg-video__content" autoplay muted loop>
                    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm">
                        Your browser is not supported!
                </video>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Your link is still broken ;)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Bsquare is there somewhere I can copy this comment so I can paste it to other new members? It's clear and not rude, like some of the others I've seen

Comment: @markmoxx Thanks :)  I build it manually, taking inspiration from some I've seen. Like me, I think you will have to copy paste, and to replace all link with the [ link name ] ( link URI ) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're using floats inside your #main div, which is why the height is 0. You need a 'clearfix' (see [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)). Specifically:

```
#main:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[Resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

You'd be better off using flexbox for your layouts (as my first link mentions), floats are becoming out of date for page layouts and are no longer best practice.

Comment: your code fixed some problems. Also the main problem was because I used the same class for header and other part of my code. I didnt realized until I updated it... By the way thanks a lot for your help and quick response! Have a nice day!